# Global Address List Not Updating in Outlook 2010

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I'm having an issue with Exchange 2010 and Outlook 2010.

Essentially, the issue is the GAL is not updating in Outlook. Every other address list updates (i.e. All Users, All Rooms, etc).

This problem started after we flattened our domain. Essentially we went from sub.domain.net *and* domain.net to solely domain.net. We migrated all the users from the the sub to the top using the ADMT and then we took down sub.domain.net.

I looked at the recipient filter of the GAL, it's below for reference:

```
(Alias -ne $null -and (ObjectClass -eq 'user' -or ObjectClass -eq 'contact' –or ObjectClass -eq 'msExchSystemMailbox' -or ObjectClass –eq 'msExchDynamicDistributionList' -or ObjectClass -eq 'group' -or ObjectClass –eq 'publicFolder'))
```

The next thing I'm going to try is creating a new GAL and making it the default, if necessary. We have another server in the wings waiting to be deployed, but we need to address the problem in the meantime.

I'm wondering if anyone has anyone has any tips that could help me address this issue.

---

Here are some things that I've tried that haven't worked:

`Update-FileDistributionService -Identity Exchange -Type OAB`

`Update-GlobalAddressList -Identity "Default Global Address List"`

`Get-OfflineAddressBook | Update-OfflineAddressBook`

I created an alternative OAB, connected it to the Default GAL, made that OAB the defualt OAB, and tried to download it through Outlook.

Restarted the Exchange Service Attendant service.

Restarted the server.

Comment: Just a tip on Manually Update Global Address List (GAL) on Exchange 2010. I have done a video and blog on this and you can view it at the below link. http://helewix.com/howto/2015/11/manually-update-global-address-list-gal-on-exchange-2010/ Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

First - you have made a common mistake. 
Are you referring to the GAL, or the OAB? I suspect the OAB. 
To be sure, does OWA (which uses live information) reflect the GAL correctly? 
If so, then the problem is with the OAB.

The first thing you should do is on a test workstation, is delete the *.oab files. That will force Outlook to download a complete GAL. Does that reflect the recent changes to the GAL? 
If so, it is probably that the incremental update files haven't updated correctly. 
If it does not, then it is the generation or distribution process that is failing.

Are you using web or public folder distribution for the OAB?

Simon.

Comment: You are correct. OWA reflects the information correctly, but Outlook does not. I am using public folders for distribution.

I have tried deleting the OAB files, but when I download the address book, it still has the outdated version.

Comment: If you are on Outlook 2010, any reason you are still using public folder distribution? The first thing I would do is switch to either web only or mixed (web and public folder). 
Then once set, run

get-offlineaddresbook | update-offlineaddressbook

Wait 20 minutes or so for it to update, then check in the Application log to see if there are any generation errors.

Comment: I didn't create the server and this is kind of my first exposure to the settings and all that. I created a new OAB with both distribution methods this morning. I ran the commands you recommended and tried it about 4 hours after that. It didn't work. As another way to troubleshoot the problem, I created a new profile for Outlook. It had all of the up-to-date information until I did a manual send/receive of the address book.

Comment: On the properties of the database, check which OAB is current configured. It could be that the new OAB you created isn't being used.